# What is a level pseudo column in Oracle, Can anyone explain me in this?

Tags: sql, oracle

What is a level pseudo column in Oracle, Can anyone explain me in this?

Comment: When did SO replace google?  Here's the first hit when you google "Oracle pseudo column": http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Pseudo-column

Comment: It would help if you accepted answers to your previous questions...

Comment: @gmagana: SO replaced Google about 3 months ago.  Why take the time to formulate a query when you can type almost anything into SO and get a response in seconds?

Comment: @gmagana: For a year old account, you haven't spent a lot of time on SO.

Comment: @gmagana It's the stated goal of Stack Overflow to become *the* extensive knowledge base on programming topics. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use LEVEL with the SELECT CONNECT BY statement to organize rows from a database table into a tree structure. LEVEL returns the level number of a node in a tree structure. The root is level 1, children of the root are level 2, grandchildren are level 3, and so on.

In the START WITH clause, you specify a condition that identifies the root of the tree. You specify the direction in which the query walks the tree (down from the root or up from the branches) with the PRIOR operator.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation I've found. Thanks much!

Comment: There's a nice description here too that compliments yours: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT LEVEL N
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 76;
```

The previous statement generates all the integers starting from 1 and ending to 75. It uses the LEVEL pseudocolumn.